# How do I stop ASP.NET div styling is overlapping/bleeding into surrounding divs?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, webforms, bootstrap-modal

When I set a div to be visible in ASP.NET webforms (yeah I know it's ancient. I work in education.), the red styling overlaps/bleeds from the div below into the div above. These divs are completely separate, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is how the mis-rendered div appears. This is inside of a bootstrap modal:
[mis-rendered div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n0R0.png)

Here is the code in the .aspx file:
[.aspx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb0xF.png)
As you can see, the two divs are completely separate. I don't know if that fact that it is within an UpdatePanel is affecting it?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px 15px;">
            <p>Please check the box when the student answers a question correctly.</p>
            <p id="VerificationInstructions" runat="server"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group alert alert-danger" id="InvalidDiv" style="margin:20px 0px 0px;" runat="server" visible="false">
            <asp:Label ID="InvalidLabel" CssClass="alert-link" runat="server" Text="" />
        </div>
```

Here is how the divs are rendered in Chrome:
[Chrome rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sgGE.png)

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px 15px;">
    <p>Please check the box when the student answers a question correctly.</p>
    <p id="ContentPlaceHolder1_VerificationInstructions">Once as student has answered 5 questions correctly, click "Finish Verification".</p>
</div>
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_InvalidDiv" class="form-group alert alert-danger" style="margin:20px 0px 0px;">
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_InvalidLabel" class="alert-link">The student must answer at least 5 questions correctly for successful verification.</span>
</div>
```

From what I can tell, it seems like the IvalidDiv is appearing behind the upper div and overlapping it. Is there some sort of element I can put between the two divs for a quick and easy fix?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: This is also a good time for you to start famiiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools, which you can use to inspect DOM elements and the styles being applied to them.

Comment: Thank you, David. I added the code in the question as text as suggested.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem so we can observe it as well?  If the problem is entirely in the client-side styling then the server-side code/framework/etc. isn't likely to be important.  The place to start would be to observe that styling and how it's producing the result you didn't expect.

Comment: Don't use UpdatePanel, use AJAX or FetchAPI in stead, you will find this a lot easier to manipulate

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px 15px;">
<p>Please check the box when the student answers a question correctly.</p>
<p id="VerificationInstructions" runat="server"></p>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="form-group alert alert-danger" id="InvalidDiv" style="margin:20px 0px 0px;" runat="server" visible="false">
<asp:Label ID="InvalidLabel" CssClass="alert-link" runat="server" Text="" />
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```